# Why do we need pure virtual functions?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I just started learning the C++, but bumped into the question about virtual functions.

I mean why do we need it? I know that it is a template for function in the child class and when making a function pure virtual forces programmers code the function body in those children classes. I know how it works.

My question is: Is pure virtual function some kind of reminder or safety component to make the code less messy?